# How can i check in first List index 1 is greater than second list index 0, and first List index 2 is greater than second list index 1. and so on

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have Three lists -

```
High:  [18365.5, 18979.25, 19297.4, 19874.8, 20288.0, 20504.65, 20398.2]
Low:  [17855.5, 18265.0, 18822.55, 18742.15, 19492.55, 20055.55, 20131.25]
Close:  [18317.05, 18969.95, 18857.6, 19804.0, 20260.15, 20285.0, 20215.7]
```

And I want to check

```
if Close [index1] > Low [index0]
   print("XYZ")
elif Close[index1] < High[index0]
   print("XYZ")
```

and as do the same for the rest of the indexes in close.

```
if Close [index2] > Low [index1]
   print("XYZ")
elif Close[index2] < High[index1]
   print("XYZ")
```

Please Help me to solve this problem. I don't understand how can I do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239929/discussion-between-user12758604-and-krishna-gupta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution as asked by you.

Correct Solution would be checking same index for all list, considering its Stock Market.

```
high = [18365.5, 18979.25, 19297.4, 19874.8, 20288.0, 20504.65, 20398.2]
low =  [17855.5, 18265.0, 18822.55, 18742.15, 19492.55, 20055.55, 20131.25]
close =  [18317.05, 18969.95, 18857.6, 19804.0, 20260.15, 20285.0, 20215.7]


for i in range(len(high)-1):
    if (close[i+1] > low[i]) and (close[i+1] < high[i]):
        print("Valid Indices")
    else:
        print("Invalid: Correct Sequence: Low < Close < High")

# Suggestion: Low =< Close =< High
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` the three lists and iterate over it. Make sure to slice `Close` correctly so that you evaluate the correct items:

```
for (high, low, close) in zip(High, Low, Close[1:]):
    if close > low:
        print("S")
    elif close < high:
        print("L")
    else:
        continue
```